# Using Matlab compiler to compile a matlab script with some python module imported

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to compile a matlab script using Matlab Application compiler. However, in the matlab script, I use a python object adb_object from adb_lib.py:

```
tmp = py.adb_lib.adb_object()
```

I've already added the *adb_lib.py* as well as '*C:\Python27\python.exe*' with **mcc -a**, but when I run the compiled exe file, it's still said:

> Undefined Variable "py" or class "py.adb_lib.adb_object".

Any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: check this documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/undefined-variable-py-or-function-py-command.html

Comment: Thank you! It turns out you need to put the module in the same folder as the compiled files.